# Quotation Marks in Twilio SMS messages

Tags: php, twilio

I am using `curl` to send SMS messages through Twilio

I'm trying to send this message...

> Bob's opinion of the word "banana" is that it is strange.

If I use the API Explorer on the Twilio website it produces this line to add to the `curl` code...

`--data-urlencode 'Body=Bob's opinion of the word "banana" is that it is strange.' \`

That is very odd to me because it **Bob's** and **"banana"** don't appear to be properly escaped. Not surprising, if I hard code it like that, it does not work.

The weird thing is that it works just fine from the API Explorer though. They are obviously doing something different behind the scenes.

Hard coding is not practical anyway so I tried this...

`--data-urlencode 'Body={$_POST['message']}' \`

...however, the SMS comes through on the phone as...

> Bob&#039;s opinion of the word &quot;banana&quot; is that it is strange.

I do need to obtain the value from $_POST['message'] so what do I need to do?

I have tried `htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['message'])` and `addslashes($_POST['message'])` and even `addslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['message']))` but am at a total loss now.

Comment: Are you calling `curl` from PHP as a shell command? Why not use PHP's robust [cURL SDK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)? Or even better, the official [twilio-php  SDK](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php)

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the -1... Not sure why you voted that way since I am using the curl commands exactly as provided by Twilio.
Turns out the code provided in the API Explorer is bogus as the ' in there is not properly escaped. Anyway... I just posted an answer as I figured it out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just edited your tags and asked a question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

...and then there was much rejoicing after the solution was found...

I first set the `$body` variable like this...

`$body=str_replace("'","'\''",htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['message']));`

...then I updated the line in the curl command from this...

`--data-urlencode 'Body={$_POST['message']}' \`

...to this...

`--data-urlencode 'Body={$body}' \`

Comment: Sounds like you may have a client-side issue if you're having to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`. What you're really looking for I think is [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.escapeshellarg.php). But again, I'd be much more inclined to use the Twilio PHP SDK

Comment: @Phil - I can't use escapeshellarg() because for the curl command it is going in, it can't have the opening and closing single quote because the opening single quote goes before 'Body=

I suppose I could add that to the string first ... escapeshellarg('Body='.$_POST['message'])